# Are All Heading Levels Required in HTML Emails?

Tags: html, html-email, html-heading

I'm working on sending a mass email. The content I was given and the template I have really don't lend themselves to an `<h1>`. There are a bunch of headings, however, that should be `<h2>`.

Is this acceptable in an email? If not, what is a method of hiding an `<h1>` that works across most email clients?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both `<h1>` and `<h2>` are not only acceptable in email, [they're *recommended* from an accessibility POV](http://blog.rebelmail.com/accessibility-in-email-part-ii/). `<h>` tags in email have the same meaning as in a web page, so you can choose whatever you think makes sense.

You may want to CSS-Reset their default visual display (also as you would in a web page). Eg:

```
h1, h2, h3 {margin: 0; padding: 0; [more reset styles...] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that common practice is to use **no** headings, or any block styles (such as p) in emails, since rendering of them can vary so widely across platforms. At the very least, you have to remember to in-line the styles of whatever you use, since some very big names in email platforms will strip out style blocks. That's generally done on the surrounding td tag.

Comment: Also one could use a span directly in the textblock to crate a headline